# How many Swarm Host for a critical mass?

Tags: starcraft-2

I've played a couple of games in HOTS multiplayer where Swarm Host have been used against me.  When there are only 4 or 5 host the locusts can be killed before they do damage (TvZ), where in the gameplay examples [from Day9](http://day9.tv/d/Day9/swarm-host-in-heart-of-the-swarm/), where there are 20 or so, they provide free kills as you don't pay for the locusts.

How many hosts should a swarm host host in HOTS?

Comment: I think this is entirely circumstantial. How many Swam Hosts it takes to overcome defenses will depend completely on what kind of defenses we are talking about.

Comment: This is way too situational. Maps? Matchups? What about unit compositions of your own and the enemy? What if the enemy is going tank-heavy mech? Number of swarm hosts become irrelevant with respect to how you are wording your question in this particular case. Another important point is regardless of how many swarmhosts you have, they are vulnerable if they aren't accompanied by other units of your own.

Comment: Now try to say that last sentence four times in a row, three times as fast..

Comment: "How many hosts should a swarm host host in HOTS?" best question on Arqade. Ever

Comment: I feel like I was setting up the punchline to a shaggy dog story - but at least I got a pretty interesting answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A you said in average competitive game **5** hosts are the **minimum** for them to reach the enemy and do any kind of damage.

Now with **10 hosts** if you focus them you will be able to kill few enemy units,and in the next wave they will kill even more units making it easy to overwhelm enemy with constant attacks since their units are costly and take more time to be produced.

Everything over 10 is desirable but depends upon the situation.Basically the best way to know if you have enough hosts is to **engage the enemy army and see how many free kills you get**,ower 3-5 killed enemies and you can easily overwhelm them.

[detailed guide](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=394256)